# Why does queryDsl query not return the same result as the exact same Oracle SQL query?

Tags: java, oracle, querydsl

Oracle query

```
SELECT a.id
FROM A a,
     B b
WHERE a.id = b.aId
  AND b.someNumber = 123456789
  AND (a.status = 'C' OR a.status = 'D');
```

Result:

> Single id result, like so: [123]

QueryDsl query:

```
QA qA = QA.a;
QB qB = QB.b;

List<Long> ids = queryFactory.select(qA.id)
        .from(qA, qB)
        .where(qB.key.aId.eq(qA.id))             // B has a object as a primary key, including the aId
        .where(qB.someNumber.eq(123456789L))
        .where(qA.status.eq("C")
                .or(qA.status.eq("D")))
        .fetch();

log(ids); // Imaginary log - no issue there (debugged it - list is empty)
```

Result:

> Empty [ ]

I would expect the queryDsl query to return the same result as the oracle one. Am I missing something?

PS: names have been changed to A and B, but the structure is 100% the same

Comment: Print the generated SQL and compare it to your hand-written SQL. Chances are they are not identical

Comment: How do I do that? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Enable SQL logging for Hibernate: https://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/ .

Apparently, id on B is mapped through a composite key. Keep in mind that all parts of a composite key must be non-null as per JPA spec / Hibernate requirement. Perhaps a `qB.key.someOtherProperty IS NOT NULL` clause is added to the query under the hood.

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `.and` rather than `.where` after the first `.where`? Also, why not use the ANSI INNER JOIN syntax?